# Why in StructureMap are Singleton classes disposed of and transients aren't

Tags: structuremap, structuremap3

In my application I've noticed that if I mark a class in the SM registry as a Singleton type it gets disposed of, however if don't specify any Singleton it doesn't get disposed of.
What and why are the reasons for this?

```
 public class IoC
{
    public static IContainer Init()
    {
        var container = new Container(x =>
        {
            x.Scan(s => {
                s.TheCallingAssembly();
                s.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory();
                s.WithDefaultConventions();                   
            });

            // disposed is called on this class but not if .Singleton() is removed
            x.For<IMyService>().Singleton();
        });

        return container;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var container = IoC.Init())
        {
            var theStory1 = container.GetInstance<MyService>();
            theStory1.TheMethod();              

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Singleton lifecycle is bound to the container's scope thus when disposing the container it takes care to dispose all singletons implementing *IDisposable*. With transients and other lifecycles like *HttpContextScoped* it is up to developer to dispose them manually when no longer need them.

Transient disposables are tricky a little bit in terms of how it should be handled. Imagine case like this one below:

```
public class ClassWithDisposableTypeDependency
{
    private readonly ISampleDisposable disposableType;

    public ClassWithDisposableTypeDependency(ISampleDisposable disposableType)
    {
        this.disposableType = disposableType;
    }

    public void SomeAction()
    {
        using (this.disposableType)
        {
            this.disposableType.DoSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

What will happend when SomAction() won't be executed? Dispose won't be called on disposableType field. In fact in this case *ClassWithDisposableTypeDependency* should also implement IDisposable and dispose its disposable dependencies.

But there is a better way to handle such cases. In mentioned case the main issue is to defer creation of a dependency to a moment when we really need that objects. We can achieve that in many ways: func, lazy, factory, etc. Here is possible solution with usage of func.

```
public class ClassWithDisposableTypeFuncDependency
{
    private readonly Func<ISampleDisposable> disposableTypeFactory;

    public ClassWithDisposableTypeFuncDependency(Func<ISampleDisposable> disposableTypeFactory)
    {
        this.disposableTypeFactory = disposableTypeFactory;
    }

    public void SomeAction()
    {
        var disposable = this.disposableTypeFactory();

        using (disposable)
        {
            disposable.DoSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

This is how we need to setup it in StructureMap:

```
var container = new Container(c => c.For<ISampleDisposable>().Use<SampleDisposable>());

var clazz = container.GetInstance<ClassWithDisposableTypeFuncDependency>();

clazz.SomeAction(); // dependency is created and disposed
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think this makes sense, but I've noticed nested containers **do** dispose. So I'm now wondering why StructureMap can track transient objects in a nested container and not a root container?

Comment: @user183872 - I've forgot to mention nested containers. Jeremy D. Miller explains here why nested containers were designed that way and how to use it - http://structuremap.github.io/the-container/nested-containers/